# Why is walri not the correct pluralization of walrus?

Tags: grammatical-number

Why is *walri* not the correct pluralization of *walrus?*

Comment: Why could the plural not be 'walrus', as in, one sheep many sheep?

Comment: I suppose it could be (in some alternative universe) but it isn't (in the real world).

Answer (score 24):

Only some words of Latin extraction ending in *-us*, which were second declension nouns in Latin, take *-i* as plural.

*Walrus* comes from Dutch, and is akin to Danish and Norwegian *hvalros*. It is not a Latin second declension noun, so there is no reason it would be pluralized with *-i*.

The plural of *walrus* is *walruses*.

**Edit:** I just want add an additional note to clarify that even in cases where an English word does come from a Latin second declension noun, its plural might not necessarily end in *-i*. For example, the plural of *campus* is *campuses* not *campi*, and the plural of *bonus* is *bonuses* not *boni*.

Comment: Exactly. Similar situation with *octopus* (which is of Greek origin), pluralised to *octopodes* if you're being 'proper'.

Comment: Aren't there also lots of Latin-derived words that don't use the Latin pluralization? I mean, we're not speaking Latin here.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New yes, you are exactly right—that’s why I said “Only **some** words of Latin extraction.”

Comment: aha, I didn't interpret your sentence that way actually; I thought you meant "Only some words  - those which were second declension nouns - take i as plural".  I guess on re-reading your statement it also (subtly, IMO) covers the point that even if Walrus WAS one of the -i nouns that doesn't mean it still IS. :)

Comment: So arguably the "correct" plural (if you're a prescriptivist who likes importing plurals) is "walrussen" or "walrusser".

Comment: If you see an error in an answer, either post a constructive comment or simply correct the error in the answer (rather than adding a postscript to the answer which points out the error). Like Wikipedia, "be bold".